# How to call functions in python

Tags: python, function

im trying to use functions in my program but im not entirely sure how to work them, i've been using python a while but never used functions can anyone explain why this isn't working for me please?

```
import csv 
import operator

def SerachForCapitals():
    #opens and reads txt file
    sample = open('Capitals.txt', 'r')
    csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter = ',')
    #asks user for an input
    name = raw_input('enter a capital: ')
    #sets the headings
    print ""
    print "Capital, Country"
    print ""
    #Finds capital row and prints it
    for row in csv1:
        if name == row[0]:
            print row
            print ' '

def AddInData():
    #opens the text file
    sample = open('capitals.txt','a+')
    csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter = ',')
    #prints headings
    print 'capital, country'
    #ask ser for an input
    change = raw_input('add data like line shown above:')
    #adds input to text file
    sample.write(change)
    #closes the text file
    sample.close()

#Menu choices
print '1. choose a capital'
print '2. enter data'
#Get an input from the user
menuC= raw_input('please choose a menu item: ')
if menuC == '1':
    SearchForCapitals()
elif menuC == '2':
    AddInData()
```

Comment: _"can anyone explain why this isn't working?"_ Isn't working how? Are you getting an error message, or what?

Comment: Look at some documentation. Hint: You've already used a few functions, including `open` and `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides from that your function definition for `SearchForCapitals` has a typo, by which I mean that the line

```
def SerachForCapitals():
```

should be

```
def SearchForCapitals():
```

(note the spelling of `Search`), your code works perfectly fine for me.

If this does not fix your problem, you should provide the output you get when running the code.

Comment: OMG! how did I not notice that. yep it works fine now lol..... Sorry to waste everyones time